# Angular: How to Retrieve the Target Url when Redirect to 404 Page

Tags: angular, routes

In my Angular application, I am handling 404 routing in this manner:

```
{
    path: '404',
    loadChildren: () =>
        import('../pages/404-pg/404-pg.module').then(
            (m) => m.FourZeroFourPgModule
        ),
},
{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/404',
}
```

The redirect works fine, but I've noticed a few 404 logs in my page navigation logs on my deployed website and am currently not logging the url which the user visited which caused the 404 redirect. How can I use the router to determine the "original" route?

For example, if I type: localhost:4200/bad-url in the browser, how can I get the "/bad-url" path using the Router object (or ActivatedRoute, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an interceptor to handle such cases.

For example,

**WHEN** you type "localhost:4200/bad-url"

**THEN** in the interceptor just before redirect you have access to the currently typed URL (`this.router.url`)

**AND** you can save it in storage as "last_route_from_error" or something like this

**THEN** user is redirected to 404 page

**AND** you have the whole URL saved in storage